# DSC: Module file *ModuleName* did not contain a module with required version 1.0

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I am trying out the new Desired state configuration stuff and trying to work with a new class resource. I have installed the pre-production preview of WMF 5.0 on all servers involved in the process.

I have a Http pull server setup where I have deployed my class resource to.

The target nodes are configured to get their resources from this server which they seem to be doing.

However when I try to push a configuration out to the target nodes that use this class resource I get the following error

> **Module file *ModuleName* did not contain a module with required version**
>   **1.0. Could not install module dependencies needed by the configuration.**

Has anyone come across this error before or knows what it means?

The SxSecurity.psm1 file has the following in which gives it the required version number:

```
@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'SxSecurity.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '1.0'

# ID used to uniquely identify this module
GUID = '00293be8-be0b-4902-9b49-12e32533a414'

# Author of this module
Author = 'Alexis.Coles'

# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = '****'

# Copyright statement for this module
Copyright = '(c) 2015 ****. All rights reserved.'

# Description of the functionality provided by this module
Description = 'Security dsc resources'

# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = @()

# Cmdlets to export from this module
CmdletsToExport = '*'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'

# DSC resources to export from this module
DscResourcesToExport = @('SxPfxImport')

# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess. This may also contain a PSData hashtable with additional module metadata used by PowerShell.
PrivateData = @{

    PSData = @{

    } # End of PSData hashtable

} 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I have fallen victim to quite a misleading error message, I think for the second time, sure I have stumbled on this before.

Maybe "Could not find Module *ModuleName*" would have pointed me more in the right direction.

It turns out that the location that DSC decided to download the module to "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" was not part of the PSModulePath environment variable.

I added the path to the environment variable restarted the server and action was resumed!